# ActiveRecord has_one with order by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to set up an ActiveRecord relationship where I have a `has_one` that returns the most recent value:

```rb
class Check < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :counts
  has_one :latest_count, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }, class_name: 'Count'
end
```

The reason for wanting it this way is to avoid N+1 queries when looking up the `latest_count`:

```rb
current_user.checks.preload(:latest_count)
```

The problem I'm running into is that preloading `latest_count` actually preloads *all* of the counts and grabs the last one in memory. Even at a small scale this is turning out to cause issues, with both memory bloat and query times increasing very quickly. Is there any way to set this relationship up so that it *only* preloads the last one? The only alternative that comes to mind for me is to add a `latest_count_id` to the `checks` table and update that whenever a new count is created.

Answer (score 1):

Update `latest_count_id` when a new `count` is created doesn't seem to be efficient.

You could try a custom `SELECT` like this:

```rb
# Example code, may need to tweak a bit

class Check
  scope :preload_latest_count, -> {
    joins.lfet_joins(:counts)
         .order("checks.id, counts.created_at DESC")
         .select("DISTINCT ON (checks.id) checks.*, counts.value AS latest_count_value")
  }
end

checks = current.checks.preload_latest_count
check = checks.first
check.latest_count_value
```

Comment: Can you tell me why using `latest_count_id` is not efficient? I think it might be faster read-wise to do a join than needing to run a `DISTINCT` query on each page visit.

Comment: @lobati Yes, using `latest_count_id` is read faster. I mean  you need to do an extra query to update `check` when a new count is created or removed.